# O que é um DTO?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, engenharia-de-software, design-pattern

Estou mexendo com Java a pouco tempo e sempre ouço a expressão DTO relacionada a puxar alguma coisa de um banco, mas nunca entendi ao certo do que se trata.

É apenas um nome para referenciar o processo de puxar informações de um banco de dados? Ou um padrão de acessos a informações nas tabelas? O que é exatamente?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

***Data Transfer Object*** (DTO) ou simplesmente ***Transfer Object*** é um padrão de projetos bastante usado em Java para o transporte de dados entre diferentes componentes de um sistema, diferentes instâncias ou processos de um sistema distribuído ou diferentes sistemas via serialização.

A ideia consiste basicamente em agrupar um conjunto de atributos numa classe simples de forma a otimizar a comunicação.

Numa chamada remota, seria ineficiente passar cada atributo individualmente. Da mesma forma seria ineficiente ou até causaria erros passar uma entidade mais complexa.

Além disso, muitas vezes os dados usados na comunicação não refletem exatamente os atributos do seu modelo. Então, um DTO seria uma classe que provê exatamente aquilo que é necessário para um determinado processo.

Em alguns casos, usa-se o DTO ou TO para mapear informações obtidas do banco de dados e então usar numa *View* (MVC). Isso não é completamente errado, e até pode otimizar a apresentação dos dados, afinal o *Controller* já recebe as informações prontas para uso. Entretanto, isso pode também acabar em um modelo muito poluído com informações redundantes.

Quando tenho um domínio bem estruturado, prefiro criar *beans* que representam esse modelo. Esses *beans* geralmente são chamados de *Entidades*. Aí, em determinados casos (como em certas pesquisas no banco de dados baseadas em *views* ou que possuem *joins* ), crio um tipo de TO ou DTO para facilitar o transporte desses dados.

Referências:

- [Data Transfer Object - Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)

Comment: e a ViewModel, tem diferença?  [Diferença entre DTO e ViewModel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305301/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-dto-e-viewmodel)

Answer (score 11):

DTO é um [padrão de projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101) usado para transportar dados de um local para outra na solução. Muitas vezes esse transporte ocorre fora do processo da aplicação, se comunicando com servidor e cliente, entre servidores ou até outras partes da solução, mas nada impede que ocorra dentro do processo.

Ele é apenas um objeto de dados, portanto não costuma ter comportamento próprio (pode ter comportamentos necessários para a linguagem conseguir trabalhar com ele, mas não dentro da semântica do próprio objeto), e como serve para transportar vem o nome Data Transport Object, ou Objeto de Transporte de Dados.

O DTO se opõe a um *model* justamente por não ter comportamentos de regras de negócio ou até mesmo de persistência ou outra forma de manipulação desses dados.

A forma de comunicação, especialmente fora do processo, não é algo que o DTO se importe ou até mesmo que saiba. É comum ser serializado, mas isso não precisa acontecer. Muito menos há formato definido para essa comunicação. O programador sabe que haverá uma comunicação, mas o DTO não sabe, não precisa saber, e não deve ser responsável por isso.

Uma dessas comunicações é com o banco de dados, e algumas aplicações só usam para isto. O criador do padrão [critica esse uso](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html), mas na prática é amplamente usado com variações.

Em geral o DTO é considerado um objeto anêmico por não ter comportamento. O comportamento dificulta o uso desses dados em outro local porque precisaria manter controle de versão e garantir que o outro lado esteja sempre sincronizado. Sem comportamentos fica muito mais fácil manter isso, embora ainda tem que sincronizar a estrutura dos dados, mas é muito mais fácil, até por ela ser mais estável.

O DTO deveria ser uma estrutura mais estática durante o tempo de vida a solução, permitindo que as classes mais completas que podem assumir outras formas sem se preocupar tanto com compatibilidade. Na prática isso não é tão fácil de alcançar.

Eu gosto de um DTO acessando campos da classe diretamente ([uso correto do termo em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)), sem [*getters/setters*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101) ou [propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101) (que é um [padrão de projeto pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324099/101) que algumas linguagens usam para facilitar o uso dos *getters/setters*). Mas algumas pessoas gostam de usar este tipo de mecanismo, e algumas ferramentas até obrigam que eles existam para conseguirem funcionar, algumas exigem forma bem específica, inclusive que o método seja virtual. Ainda assim não deve ter um comportamento real, além de acessar e mudar o valor do campo.

Note que DTO não é algo do Java, e funciona igual em todas tecnologias, podendo até mesmo ser usado entre linguagens diferentes. O que pode ser específico, nem do Java, mas de um *framework* específico, é a forma de implementar o DTO.

O objetivo geral é a simplificação do trabalho de transporte. Nem quer buscar eficiência em si, embora possa alcançar isso também dependendo de como se faria sem ele. A eficiência vem mais da forma de comunicação e não da estrutura dos dados. Um motivo mais claro de uso dele é manter uma forma mais universal de dados que pode ser diferente do que a aplicação consome de fato em cada lado, então o DTO tende ser diferente da classe da aplicação. Em muitos casos é exatamente igual, só a falta dos comportamentos é diferença.

O mais comum é seu uso com outros *design patterns*, como DAO, Active Record, serialização, RPC, CQRS e outros. Depende da aplicação dele.

[Veja mais](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html).

[image: Esquema mostrando o uso de DTO]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).