# Como passar lista de objetos para Subreport?

Tags: java, ireport, relatório

Tenho o plugin do iReport no netbeans. Ja configurei os classpath para reconhecer minhas classes, faço os seguintes passos:

1 º - Enviar a lista de objetos `Boletim` para o report principal, cada boletim tem informações de um aluno. (Essa parte funciona, consigo gerar os dados).

2 º - Enviar as **7 listas de NOTAS** para o subreport, dentro do objeto `Boletim` tem um objeto *Bimestre1*, *Bim2*, *B3*, *B4*, *Exame*, *Media Anual* e *Media Final* que são do tipo `Bimestre`.
Cada `Bimestre` possui uma lista de `Notas`, Cada nota possui os atributos de nome da materia, nota e falta.

Preciso enviar pro subreport todas as listas de notas.

Portanto eu preciso enviar dessa forma as listas para o subreport

```
boletim.getBimestre1().getNotas(); //List<Nota>
boletim.getBimestre2().getNotas();//List<Nota>
boletim.getBimestre3().getNotas(); //List<Nota>
boletim.getBimestre4().getNotas();//List<Nota>
boletim.getExame().getNotas(); //List<Nota>
boletim.getNotasAnuais(); //List<Nota>
boletim.getNotasFinais(); //List<Nota>
```

Todas essas listas enviadas tem o mesmo tamanho, para cada iteração na `banda DETAIL do subreport` seja acessado a proxima nota das lista passadas

**Relatório principal** - aqui contem o objeto Boletim, onde tem os dados da turma e do aluno. Tambem tem as listas de notas, essas devem ser enviadas para o subreport.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu Subrelatório** (aqui deve receber as 7 listas de notas, para poder adicionar as informações nas linhas abaixo do header, onde está em branco as células.)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisando um pouco dessa [forma](http://www.guj.com.br/729-como-listar-objetos-em-um-subreport) da certo, mas só envia uma lista, preciso enviar no minimo 7 listas

Answer (score 0):

Particularmente não gosto muito de deixar a inteligencia para o Jasper, minha sugestão é você criar um [DTO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31362/o-que-%C3%A9-um-dto) de notas por disciplina, e preencheria esta no java.

A ideia é que esse DTO contenha como atributos cada uma das colunas que você necessita no relatório.

```
public class NotaDTO {
    String disciplina;
    Double notaPrimeiroBimestre;
    Double notaSegundoBimestre;
    Double notaTerceiroBimestre;
    Double mediaAnual;
    Double mediaFinal;
    Integer falta;
}
```

Você deve então preencher com as informações dessas lista (no seu caso 7) com as informações referentes a cada disciplina/bimestre. Dessa forma você passaria somente uma lista do seu NotaDTO como Collection do seu subreport.

Obs: Sugiro que repense a forma como estruturou seu projeto, porque não existe um objeto para representar a Disciplina?

Comment: A minha solução a primeiro momento foi essa, mas isso gera muitos dados duplicados. Não vejo como a melhor solução.

Comment: Mas essa DTO seria uma lista temporária, não persistida, criada no momento que o relatório fosse gerado, com intuito de facilitar o trabalho do jasper.