# O que é Design Pattern?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, terminologia

Estou iniciando meus estudos na área de Engenharia de Software, ouvi muito a respeito do termo Design Patterns e sua aplicabilidade e importância em projetos de software. Segue abaixo uma definição:

> *Em engenharia de software, um **padrão de projeto ou padrão de desenho
>   (do inglês design pattern)** é uma solução geral reutilizável para um
>   problema que ocorre com frequência dentro de um determinado contexto
>   no projeto de software.*

Fonte: [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software)

Eu não consegui visualizar o que seriam `Design Patterns`. Mas afinal, o que ele é? Alguém poderia elucidar o que devemos levar em consideração para buscarmos aplicar estes conceitos em um projeto de software? Talvez isso melhore no meu entendimento.

Comment: Veja se [**isso**](http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/design-patterns/o-que-sao-design-patterns.html) te ajuda a entender, eu dei uma lida e achei bem esclarecedor.

Comment: Design Pattern é quando você usa Singleton (lol).

Comment: Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Até iria criar uma resposta à parte, mas as outras respostas falam praticamente tudo. Te indico esse site pra dar uma olhada: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns . Além disso, recomendo dar uma olhada nos cursos da Alura (não estou fazendo propaganda, apenas fiz eles e achei ótimos) ou outros sobre o tema, pra ter uma ideia mais clara sobre o tema e onde aplicá-lo na prática.

Answer (score 35):

Normalmente enxergamos o padrão de projeto como uma receita de bolo. É um modelo a ser seguido. É uma forma de codificar algo para obter um determinado resultado, uma determinada solução. Normalmente estas receitas foram criadas por quem já teve o problema, pensou muito a respeito e encontrou uma solução que pode ser universal.

As receitas focam mais em problemas bem específicos e provavelmente de forma [idiomática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184238/101). Os DPs são mais conceituais e focam no problema, mais que na implementação.

Padrões de projeto são ideias, não são ferramentas, tecnologias, produtos, metodologias, paradigmas, etc.

Existem alguns padrões famosos que são muito comuns em diversas aplicações, mas nada impede de você estabelecer seus próprios padrões para aplicações específicas, se ele pode se repetir no seu trabalho.

Alguns destes padrões são documentados e exemplos são fornecidos. Alguns podem ser mais automatizados e uma biblioteca ou *framework* pode ser disponibilizada para facilitar sua implementação e uso.

Outros são tão comuns que podem ser inseridos dentro das linguagens de programação para facilitar ainda mais.

## Padrões que ganharam fama

Quando as pessoas pensam em *design pattern* é comum pensar nos principais, nos [definidos pelo grupo Gang of Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). Também pensam em padrões como o MVC (ainda que seja mais um padrão de arquitetura) e outros semelhantes, mas esquecem que tudo é padrão de projeto.

## Padrões estão em todo lugar

As linguagens de programação de alto nível são todas baseadas em padrões de projeto que eram usados quando se programava em *assembly* nos primórdios da computação. Faziam alguns padrões de código frequentemente então seria melhor abstrair isso.

Por exemplo, uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é uma padrão de projeto para acessar um valor em determinado endereço da memória. Você não vai ler isto em nenhuma lista de padrões, afinal ele se tornou tão comum, tão transparente, que ninguém mais pensa nele como um padrão.

As construções de controle de fluxo das linguagens são *design patterns* que decidem e desviam a ordem de execução das instruções.

A programação orientada a objeto é um paradigma composto por um conjunto de padrões de projeto. Então até [dá para programar OO sem uma linguagem própria para isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80228/101).

A herança é uma forma de reuso de código que aproveita um padrão estabelecido em outra classe.

Quando usa um dicionário está usando um padrão de acesso a uma estrutura de dados de chave e valor. Quando faz um *quicksort*, está usando um padrão.

## Usando certo

É um erro reduzir os padrões a estes conhecidos, e mais ainda, tentar adaptar todo código a um padrão. Existem os que programam "orientado a padrões", e costumam cometer atrocidades no código por causa disto. Na verdade o GoF veio para disseminar o termo, mas também para deturpar o que ele realmente é. Não se deixe levar pela utilização da moda. Isto limita a real utilidade dele.

Tem que saber quando adotá-lo, quando adaptá-lo e quando ignorá-lo. É claro que se não conhecer todos os mais conhecidos você corre o risco de reinventar a roda de forma pior, mas tentar usar um padrão onde não cabe, também traz resultados desastrosos. Não precisa ficar procurando padrão em tudo.

Quando você pensa em sua aplicação como se estivesse sempre criando um padrão novo pode ser mais fácil descobrir se já existe um que pode ser aplicando, ou pode facilitar a clareza do que está fazendo. Soluções reutilizáveis normalmente são mais claras.

Padrões formalizados possuem um nome significativo, uma explicação, um contexto e exemplo de implementação.

Além do GoF, existem outras coletâneas de padrões: [A Pattern Language](https://www.patternlanguage.com/), [Portland](http://c2.com/ppr/checks.html), [Coplien](https://sites.google.com/a/gertrudandcope.com/info/Publications/Patterns/PLoP95-telecom), [POSA](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/%7Eschmidt/POSA/) e [EAA](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/), só para citar os mais conhecidos.

[Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16204/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/07e2ddadd3afb60ea34a2d125e75c5768c315930/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 22):

Design pattern é o termo usado para descrever uma solução a um problema que ocorre com frequencia e também um forma de resumir a ideia de uma implementação de código, ao invés de descrever o código você fala apenas, estou usando um strategy. Eles também são aplicados para suprir algumas deficiências da linguagem utilizada.

Um padrão de projeto possui várias sessões que são importantes para saber se ele deve ou não ser adotado como

**Cenário**: Onde a solução se aplica e por que.

**Vantagens**: Porque essa abordagem resolve o problema de forma elegante.

**Desvantagens**: Em quais casos a solução não se aplica ou acaba tornando seu projeto mais complexo, pois normalmente várias classes novas adicionadas no projeto, que trabalham em conjunto entre si para resolver o problema.

**Diagrama de classe/organização**: Mostra a estrutura de classes do padrão e como elas se relacionam.

**Implementação**: É o código em si, a implementação pode variar bastante de uma linguagem para outra, lembre o padrão **é apenas uma idea** de como resolver o problema e não uma bala de prata.

Answer (score 12):

### Padrões de Projeto

Apesar de específicos, os sistemas corporativos possuem diversas características semelhantes. Consequentemente, muitos problemas se repetem em contextos distintos.

Suponha que um determinado problema ocorrerá em duzentos sistemas diferentes. Em cada sistema, esse problema pode ser resolvido de uma forma distinta. Então, globalmente, teríamos duzentas soluções para o mesmo problema. Provavelmente, algumas soluções seriam melhores que
outras ou até mesmo uma delas melhor do que todas as outras.

Daí surge o conceito de **padrão de projeto** ou **design pattern**. Um padrão de projeto é uma solução consolidada para um problema recorrente no desenvolvimento e manutenção de software orientado a objetos.

A referência mais importante relacionada a padrões de projeto é o livro *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* (editora Addison-Wesley, 1995) dos autores Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson e John Vlissides. Esses quatro autores são conhecidos como “Gang of Four”(GoF). Os diagramas UML apresentados nesta apostila são baseados nos diagramas desse livro.

### Padrões GoF

Os padrões definidos no livro *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* são
denominados padrões GoF. Eles são classificados em três categorias: padrões de **criação**, **estruturais** e **comportamentais**.

**Fonte:**

[K51 - Design Patterns em Java](http://www.k19.com.br/downloads/apostilas/java/k19-k51-design-patterns-em-java)

**Leitura recomendada**
[Source Making - Design Patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)

[WebPro - Programming Principles](http://webpro.github.io/programming-principles/)

Answer (score 9):

O problema de explicar o que são *Design Patterns* é que a explicação tende a ficar abstrata, porque o conceito em si é um tanto abstrato, e portanto para quem é iniciante fica difícil de entender.

Uma forma mais concreta de explicar é assim: um *Design Pattern* é uma determinada combinação de classes/interfaces que juntas resolvem um tipo de problema que é comum de acontecer em desenvolvimento de software. Essas classes/interfaces podem precisar de adaptação para o problema em si.

Exemplos:

- O *pattern* *Observer*, cujo diagrama de classes é [assim](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/Observer.svg/1000px-Observer.svg.png), resolve o problema de notificar outras classes que um evento aconteceu.
- O *pattern* *Iterator*, que tem [este](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRaic_998v3CWygwGdODT7LdPP6WBiSjk8OfQlk-lLRLR-pbkX) diagrama de classes, resolve o problema de percorrer os elementos armazenados em um objeto *container* (uma lista, conjunto, dicionário, etc.) de uma maneira que não dependa de como o *container* é implementado.
- O *pattern* *Singleton* impede que uma classe seja instanciada mais do que uma única vez.

Essas soluções em geral são elegantes e oferecem boa manutenabilidade, isto é, tornam o software bem preparado para aceitar mudanças naquele ponto do sistema em que o *pattern* foi aplicado.

Tornou-se interessante catalogar essas combinações para que as pessoas tomem conhecimento e, caso esbarrem em um problema do mesmo tipo, usem o *pattern* em vez ficarem reinventando a roda com soluções que muitas vezes podem ter baixa manutenabilidade.

Porém, é preciso tomar o cuidado de escolher o *pattern* certo para solucionar o problema, isto **se** a melhor solução for um *pattern*.

Quando a pessoa encontra uma situação e pensa *"talvez o pattern X se aplique aqui"*, ela precisa avaliar com cuidado se o *pattern* é realmente aplicável àquela situação, usando seu conhecimento sobre o *pattern* (escopo, intenção, etc.) e procurando comparar o problema que está sendo enfrentado com o tipo de problema que o *pattern* se propõe a resolver.

Um *pattern* mal aplicado pode aumentar a complexidade do software desnecessariamente.

Answer (score 5):

Um *design pattern* é uma solução geral para resolver um problema que ocorre com frequência em um contexto de desenvolvimento/projeto de software.

A maior referência que eu conheço sobre *design pattern* é o livro Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software. Os quatro autores são conhecidos como *Gang of Four* (A gangue dos quatro - em tradução livre), porque o livro é um catálogo dos 23 padrões de projetos mais conhecidos.

---

Os padrões podem ser classificados em 3:

- Padrões de Criação - Eles abstraem o processo de instanciação, tornam um sistema independente da forma como os objetos são criados, compostos e representados
- Padrões Estruturais.  São aqueles que lidam com a composição de classes (ou objetos) para formar grandes estruturas no sistema;
- Padrões Comportamentais. Eles caracterizam a forma como classes (ou objetos) interagem e distribuem responsabilidade;

---

Quais são os padrões existentes?

- De criação: Abstract Factory, Builder, Factory Method, Prototype e Singleton;
- Padrões Estruturais: Adapter, Bridge, Composite, Decorator, Facade, Flyweight e Proxy;
- Padrões de Comportamento: Chain of Responsibility, Command, Interpreter, Iterator, Mediator, Memento, Observer, State, Strategy, Template Method e Visitor

> mais tarde vou completar essa resposta.

Comment: "Mais tarde" quando?

Comment: Hoje é 22/05/2020, já é mais tarde?