# Aplicação de mais de um design pattern

Tags: mvc, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software

Estive estudando sobre *design patterns* e achei bem legal, mas teve uma coisa que não consegui entender. Em relação aos *design patterns*, posso aplicar mais de um deles no mesmo projeto? Independente de qual seja (ex: Singleton, Observer, Builder, etc.), eu posso usar mais um numa solução que eu venha desenvolver?

Pretendo fazer uma solução em php e queria iniciá-la depois de sanar essa dúvida.
Eu queria colocar o MVC, mas não sei se ele é considerado um *design pattern* também.

Comment: Sim pode usar quantos quiser, você deve usar eles quando tiver aquele problema especifico usar por usar não ajuda em nada, exceto do caso de um trabalho onde é pedido para usar 3 ou mais design patterns.

Comment: E quanto ao mvc, ele é considerado um design pattern também?

Comment: Pelo curso que eu fiz, sim. E cada um deles pode implementar um padrão diferente!

Comment: Que diferença faz se ele é ou não um padrão? (eu acho que é um padrão arquitetural, mas não tenho certeza, nem estou interessado em saber) Se ele se aplica ao seu caso, use! O problema é só quando dois ou mais padrões diferentes tentam resolver o mesmo problema de formas diferentes, e são incompatíveis um com o outro (tipo MVC vs MVVM vs MVP vs MVA). Mas num projeto como um todo, se parte dele se encaixa mais num padrão, parte em outro, parte nos dois, parte em nenhum, você usa o padrão que precisa quando precisa.

Comment: P.S. Eu havia feito um comentário relevante numa outra pergunta, mas acho que foi removida, pois não o encontro, então vou repetir aqui: o problema de se estudar padrões quando se é iniciante é que eles acabam sendo vistos como um "livro de receitas" onde você escolhe um, aplica do jeitinho que está lá e pronto, mas sem entender de fato o propósito por trás dele, sem ganhar **experiência** na resolução do problema. Pois o natural é, ao se resolver N problemas e perceber algo comum em todos eles, abstrair essa característica comum em um conceito reutilizável - o padrão.

Comment: Um bom motivo para o MVC não ser considerado um design pattern (no sentido dos 23 design patterns do GoF) é ele ser citado no livro do GoF e mesmo assim não estar na lista de patterns deles. A Wikipedia em inglês o trata como padrão arquitetural, o que faz bastante sentido. Eu já tentei corrigir a Wiki em português algumas vezes, mas sempre vinha algum teimoso e desfazia a correção, aí desisti.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Provavelmente não estudou o suficiente sobre ele e ainda está apegado à regras que criaram artificialmente sobre isto. Você já usa [padrões de projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101) o tempo todo, mesmo sem perceber. Esqueça isto como regras, como receitas, como "boas práticas", como algo a ser seguido.

E claro que pode usar vários, caso contrário não seria possível criar nada útil. Codificar é juntar uma série de padrões juntos para alcançar um resultado. Mesmo que estes padrões não sejam documentados em algum livro, não sejam famosos, ou mesmo que eles sejam tão usados, tão óbvio e já implementados na linguagem que você nem se dá conta que é um padrão.

Quando você começa pensar em padrões como sendo aqueles listados pelo Gang of Four, ou em [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) e coisas do tipo, você comete dois erros: 1) não enxerga o todo; 2) fica tentando aplicar padrão complexo onde a coisa é simples. Ou seja, fica procurando problema para aplicar a ferramenta, quando o correto é fazer o oposto.

Não importa se o MVC é um padrão de projeto ou não, importa se você precisa dele ou não. Vai importar se estiver escrevendo uma monografia ou algo assim que tenha que definir o MVC, mas no trabalho de desenvolvimento, se ele é isto ou se ele é um modelo de arquitetura, ou tenha outra definição, é irrelevante. A dúvida ocorre justamente por não ter entendido ainda a finalidade do tal do *design pattern*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: vlw bigown, vou estudar mais sobre o assunto para me aprofundar.