# Como criar fórmulas em tempo de execução em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, script, reflexão

Existem muitas vantagens quando as coisas mudam para melhor, assim foram as mudanças do Clipper para Delphi e C#, na verdade apenas na parte visual. Havia no Clipper um recurso fantástico chamado MACRO SUBSTITUIÇÃO.

Bom, em Clipper era possível criar fórmulas utilizando a Macro Substituição, onde o usuário poderia cria-las ou usar as padrões que eram armazenadas no banco de dados.

Um exemplo simples seria o calculo do salário de um indivíduo, conforme segue:

```
{
    var SB = 1200,00;
    var HM = 220;
    var HT = 215;
    var VP = 0;

    var sFormula = 'HT * (SB / HM)';

    VP = &sFormula;
}
```

Onde:
  - **SB** = Salário Base
  - **HM** = Horas Mensais
  - **HT** = Horas Trabalhadas
  - **VP** = Valor do Pagamento

Como SB, HM e HT podem mudar de colaborador pra colaborador, estes seriam valores recebidos em uma função que retornaria o valor de VP que seria 1172,73;  Este mesmo processo para calcular todos os eventos da Folha de Pagamento.

Porque este método, porque dá liberdade a Empresa de criar toda e qualquer formula que achar necessário para efetuar algum cálculo, a única limitação seria o uso das siglas utilizadas nas fórmulas pois são definidas pelo software, porém incluir mais siglas seria um processo simples.

Sei que isto é possível em PHP e preciso saber se alguém tem conhecimento de como faze-lo em C#.

Comment: Ora, apenas crie um micro parser. O usuário entra com o formato em algum campo textual e sua aplicação analisa depois de "tokenizar" a string para as correspondentes variáveis no seu código. É muito mais seguro assim, muita gente mexendo no código como você disse não é algo NADA legal. Isso que você quer é CONFIGURAÇÃO. Torne seu programa configurável. Essa ideia do Clipper é péssima!

Comment: Há uma seção no ótimo livro THE PRAGMATIC PROGRAMER que diz: *Configure, Don’t Integrate*

Comment: @felipsmartins a ideia era do dBase e o Clipper foi obrigado manter por compatibilidade. Mas a ideia péssima não é do Clipper. É do programador que a usa :)

Comment: Infelizmente o Harbour herdou a macro pelo mesmo motivo, compatibilidade. Espero um dia poder recompilar (nem que seja fazendo um fork) sem o runtime da macro. Quanto ao problema da pergunta, um parser básico, como o felipe já comentou, resolve sem os efeitos colaterais danosos da macro.

Comment: bigown - Primeiro, DBase não tem este recuso disponível, mas o Clipper herdou do C, pelo qual fora desenvolvido; como coloquei acima, o mal uso do recurso dá-se pela incapacidade ou preguiça de quem desenvolve em desenvolver os controles necessários. Tem muitos programadores que se acham o cara, mas se acham tá longe, pois ser mesmo, são os que apresentam soluções e não críticas, os críticos (negativos), são pessoas decepcionas com a vida e seu potencial, se odeiam por não conseguirem ser bons como os colegam em volta, daí não falam nada de bom, pois não tem com que contribuir. Simples assim!

Comment: @ArnaldoOliveira A resposta resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

## Abuso de macros

O uso de macros em Clipper era uma grande gambiarra que trazia vários problemas e frequentemente era abusado, como é o caso do exemplo mostrado.

Não existe nenhuma razão para fazer isso a não ser desconhecimento ou preguiça de fazer do jeito certo. A maioria dos locais onde se usava macro podia ser fazer sem a macro de forma até mais simples e certamente mais segura. O caso da compilação de fórmula arbitrária era um caso que poderia ser justificável, mas não é. Até o [Harbour](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbour_(compilador)) possui uma solução melhor que o Clipper, fazendo a compilação do jeito certo e permitindo salvar e carregar blocos de código compilados.

Vamos supor que realmente queira deixar usuários digitarem fórmulas por conta própria. Isto é temerário e deveria vir acompanhada de um compilador próprio para garantir que tudo está ok e não está fazendo nada a mais do que deveria. A utilização da macro é um enorme buraco de segurança. Para quem não sabe o que é e está se perguntando o que seria isso, é o `eval()` do JavaScript.

## Equivalente em C#

Em linguagens estáticas e totalmente compiladas é mais complicado fazer isso. C# até provê algumas formas por rodar em uma máquina virtual (também daria em um *runtime* mais completo). Mas antes de fazer isto procure usar as ferramentas certas de uma linguagem estática. Procure saber sobre os [padrões de projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101) estruturais, especialmente o [*Strategy pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) que eu acho que é o que realmente precisa. Ele não permitirá o usuário digitar fórmulas mas facilitará a inclusão de fórmulas para personalizar o software. Essas fórmulas serão previamente compiladas e possivelmente validadas pelo fornecedor do software. Tem várias técnicas a serem seguidas para criar um sistema seguro de *plugin* que realize isso de forma adequada.

Outra possibilidade para realmente deixar o usuário digitar a fórmula é criar um compilador para isto.

O C# sempre permitiu gerar código em tempo de execução, mas era complicado, com o [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) ficou bem mais fácil. Dá até pra simular o que a macro do Clipper fazia de forma razoavelmente simples, e se abstrair, a sintaxe fica até parecida. Mas o fato de poder gerar código a partir em um fonte não significa que deva fazer, não significa que uma série de medidas de segurança não devam ser tomadas, e são medidas razoavelmente complicadas de implementar.

Um exemplo da API de *scripting*:

```
int result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>("1 + 2");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/EvaluateCode.cs).

Um início de [documentação](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) pode ser encontrado no GitHub da Microsoft.

Acho o `Async` desnecessário em casos simples assim, mas nem sei se a versão atual possui uma forma síncrona de execução.

## Conclusão

Reforço que isso não deveria ser usado por quem não tem completo entendimento de todas as implicações do seu uso e sabe como resolver tudo ou aceita que o código seja temerário. "Deveria ter uma lei" obrigando um código assim só poder ser usado com expressa anuência do usuário. Embora seja verdade que usuário que for prejudicado por causa disto e não foi notificado do risco (em alguns casos até se foi notificado), poderá certamente processar quem o expôs desta forma.

Comment: Fato:1. "era uma grande gambiarra que trazia vários problemas" - Verdade, trazia vários, se não muitos, para quem não sabia como utiliza-lo, isto é verdade!

Comment: Fato: 2. "Vamos supor que realmente queira deixar usuários digitarem fórmulas por conta própria. Isto é temerário", sim, verdade, se o desenvolvedor é preguiçoso e não valida as informações antes de processá-las.

Comment: Fato: 3. "Procure saber sobre os padrões de projeto estruturais, especialmente o Strategy pattern que eu acho que é o que realmente precisa." finalmente algo útil.

Comment: Fato: 4. "Um início de documentação pode ser encontrado no GitHub da Microsoft. Ainda não há uma documentação oficial definitiva." algo útil também! Parabéns, está melhorando.

Comment: Fato: 5. "Reforço que isto não deveria ser usado por quem não tem completo entendimento de todas as implicações do seu uso", pois é, se as experiências no passado não foram boas, vale o dizer: Tolo o que não aprende das experiências dos outros, mas imbecil o que não aprende das próprias. Logo, minhas experiências sempre foram boas, pois sempre fiz as devidas validações para que haja segurança quanto a validade das informações, pois o que dá errado, não é que não presta, mas pelo desenvolvedor preguiçoso que aplica mal o método ou pelo medíocre que lê um livro já é programador. ;-)

Comment: Se você tem capacidade intelectual ou potencial profissional para responder minha pergunta, poste algo sobre BOAS PRÁTICAS ou um caso de uso.   Deixe suas frustrações e tente, ao menos tente, ser ético e profissional, ou melhor, não comente. Faço suas as minhas palavras: "Não existe nenhuma razão para fazer isto a não ser desconhecimento ou preguiça de fazer do jeito certo."; e o jeito certo é postar um caminho, de preferência o correto, assim você agrega valor, mostra teu conhecimento e torna-se útil a você mesmo e aos em torno.  Valeu bigown!  ->  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUO-o_Bg8AY

Comment: Boas práticas não existem. Existe conhecimento ou falta dele. Boa prática é sinônimo de "vou fazer como ouvi falar que é bom, pq eu nao tenho condição técnica de decidir se nesse caso é certo ou não".

Comment: @Bacco - Concordo contigo!