# Fazer conta com PHP na ordem que está na string

Tags: php, string

Preciso que uma ordem de calculo que esteja na *string* seja feita na ordem que está nela. Por exemplo:

```
$string = '(10*10)+(30-5)/2';
```

Preciso que o PHP interprete isso não como uma *string*, mas sim como um cálculo e faça de acordo com o que tem que ser feito. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso:

```
$string = '(10*10)+(30-5)/2';
eval( '$result = (' . $string. ');' );
echo $result;
```

**Obs:** Como você deve saber a divisão vem antes da soma, então o resultado será: 112.5

Caso você queira que a divisão ocorra por último. Adicione mais um parênteses a sua equação. Veja: ((10*10)+(30-5))/2

Answer (score 9):

Resolvi dar uma resposta complementar sobre o `eval()` que é uma solução válida. Isso pode ser vista em [Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101).

Pra falar a verdade qualquer informação sobre o `eval()` que não tenha essa ressalva pra mim beira a ser errada.

Usar o `eval()` é perigosíssimo. Até dá para usá-lo sem correr grandes riscos, mas quase ninguém sabe fazer isso, portanto é melhor não tentar antes de ter certeza que entende todos os riscos e sabe como resolvê-los. É tão complicado fazer certo que muitas vezes é melhor usar forma mais complexa que ele.

A pergunta não deixa claro de onde vem essa informação. Se vem de de um cliente, então esquece o `eval()`, o trabalho para garantir segurança nele é tão grande que fazer o compilador de fórmula simples para o que precisa é mais simples. Talvez dê até pra fazer com `RegEx`, que eu não gosto, mas é uma solução. A solução passa por um [parser](/questions/tagged/parser).

Se a informação não vem externamente, aí é provável que seja seguro, porém, pra que usaria um `eval()` em algo que não vem externamente? Pode existir um motivo, mas é pouco provável que seja o mecanismo certo. Já vi muita gente usando recurso desse tipo, por [preguiça de digitar códigos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/109213/101). Esse é um motivo muito errado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/79610)

Comment: Eu acho que fornece uma resposta e mais importante que a resposta aceita, afinal diz que o `eval()` pode ser feito, mas não deve ser usado e dá a solução real, só não dá um *parser* completo porque não foi o perguntado e seria muito ampla. Eu sei que o AP vai seguir o caminho fácil e inseguro, mas serve para as pessoas que se preocupam com segurança entenderem que isso não é uma solução adequada.

Comment: Não discordo do que disse, é sim importante, só discordo disto ser uma resposta, pois fala como pode ser feito mas não apresenta um exemplo para determinar como uma resposta completa, acho que caberia mais como comentário de recomendação.

Comment: Mas ainda é uma resposta, você só discorda do que foi colocado. Na verdade hoje na moderação eu vejo as sinalizações e percebo que muita gente não sabe o que é um resposta ou não, tenho que recusar um monte. Note o texto que é colocado quando escolhe essa opção e me diga se ele faz algum sentido aqui. O exemplo só poderia ser dado dando um código que sequer caberia em uma resposta. Pelo menos na forma que eu faria. Mas há uma informação nova dada,cabe ao autor fazer perguntas mais específicas se tiver interesse, o que já vimos que não há, ele já escolheu a solução arriscada

Answer (score 3):

Como complemento à resposta já dada, decidi postar uma solução que tenho sobre o assunto.

Existe um componente do Symfony chamado [Expression Language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html), que pode facilitar seu serviço. Com ele você pode utilizar expressões simples, através de `strings`, que serão interpretadas por um parser e obter o resultado em php.

Veja:

```
use Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\ExpressionLanguage;

$language = new ExpressionLanguage();

var_dump($language->evaluate('1 + 2')); // displays 3

var_dump($language->compile('1 + 2')); // displays (1 + 2)
```

Não sei ao certo, mas parece-me que a sintaxe interpretada por essa biblioteca é bem similar a do [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Nada contra a resposta do `eval`, mas como dito pelo [@Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown), é bom se precaver e saber o que está fazendo, para não colocar sua aplicação em risco.

Comment: E existe algum motivo para ele ser mais seguro, ou tem o mesmo problema do `eval()`?

Comment: @bigown as expressões que ele utiliza, até onde eu vi, não faz coisas do tipo: conexão com banco, alteração de arquivos. Parece se tratar mais de um parser para template.

Comment: Então você não entendeu onde está o problema de segurança e não deveria usar esse tipo de coisa :)