# Executar código contido em string em C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, eval

Sou iniciante em C# e montei um código dentro de uma string e preciso que seja executado.

```
string MyString = "MyPictureBox.BackColor = Color.Red;";
```

Encontrei outras perguntas semelhantes (inclusive peço desculpas por isso) mas ainda não obtive êxito... Há, em C#, como o fazer de forma simples?

Comment: Veja isto também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109211/101

Comment: var engine = new ScriptEngine();
            engine.Execute(MyString);