# Linguagem para processamento de regras de negócio

Tags: c#, mobile, característica-linguagem, regra-de-negócio

Estou arquitetando um novo projeto em C# e uma das necessidades é que modulo faça cálculos matemáticos em cima de valores que vou ter no banco de dados.

Esse modulo precisa compartilhar essas regras com um outro projeto Mobile sendo sincronizado caso as regras mudem.

Peço sugestões para com alguma técnica ou linguagens que possam ser usadas como *scripts* que possam rodar entre as plataformas.

A principio pensei em JavaScript, pois pode ser processada pelo modulo em C# e o Mobile usando o *views* de navegação (ex. Android WebView, iOS UIWebKit).

Comment: Conhece arquitetura SOA? Tente criar uma API Restful para atender as 2 aplicações utilizando o mesmo back-end aonde você centralizará as regras de negócio, e nas aplicações front-end (mobile e desktop) .
Sugiro o artigo:
http://www.ciceroednilson.com.br/criando-um-servico-restful-com-web-api-em-c/

Comment: Esqueci de comentar, estamos fazendo dessa forma pois um dos requisitos do projeto é que o Mobile trabalhe Offline, por dificuldades de conexão no local dos que vão opera-lo.

Comment: Você esta pensando em termos de tecnologia, quando na verdade precisa pensar em termos de arquitetura.Seu problema não é a linguagem. EX.: https://www.mulesoft.com/resources/api/microservices-vs-monolithic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se precisa de algo no servidor e no mobile pode usar o [Xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e ficar no C#.

Não me parece que realmente precise de uma linguagem de *script*, mas se precisar mesmo, pode ser [o próprio C# como *script*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109211/101)? Isso é obtido através do [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101).

Se precisa que seja web mesmo, não consegue escapar do JavaScript. Pode no máximo usar uma linguagem que rode em cima do JS. Pode ser o [TypeScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101) ou até [mesmo o C#](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS#c-f-net-related-languages), apesar que aí o resultado pode não ser muito bom e provavelmente precisará de adaptações.

Outra alternativa é deixar tudo no servidor e o cliente só solicitar o processamento do servidor. Isso tem vantagens e desvantagens. Você tem que ver se serve para você.

Comment: Estamos usando o Xamarin para o Mobile, e temos experiencia com o Roslyn em projetos Desktop, mas não sei como estão para as plataformas Mobile em cima do Mono. Bom como foi comentado e já era uma de nossas alternativas, vou fazer alguns testes pra ver se vinga. Obrigado

Comment: Mobile é para usar o Xamarin, ponto.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, para necessidades de regras de negócio únicas para todos os devices que possam acessar, eu lhe recomendaria criar uma WebAPI e todos os dispositivos efetuem chamadas a tal API. Desta forma, uma vez que a regra de negócio for alterada, isso se torna transparente a todos os dispositivos clientes.

Comment: Esqueci de comentar, estamos fazendo dessa forma pois um dos requisitos do projeto é que o Mobile trabalhe Offline, por dificuldades de conexão no local dos que vão opera-lo.

Comment: Edite a pergunta principal e adicione os requisitos la.