# Classificações de padrões de projeto

Tags: design-pattern

Meu professor da faculdade passou a seguinte classificação dos padrões de projeto:

- Criacionais: Abstract Factory; Builder; Factory Method; Prototype e Singleton.
- Comportamentais: Bridge; Command; FlyWeigth; Iterator; Observer; State; Strategy e Template Method.
- Estruturais: Adapter; Chair of Responsability; Composite; Decorator; Facade; Interpreter; Mediator; Memento; Proxy e Visitor.

Na internet encontrei o seguinte sobre os padrões GoF:

- De criação: Abstract Factory; Builder; Factory Method; Prototype e Singleton.
- Comportamentais: Chain of Responsibility; Command; Interpreter; Iterator; Mediator; Memento; Observer; State; Strategy; Template Method e Visitor.
- Estruturais: Adapter; Bridge; Composite; Decorator; Façade; Flyweight e Proxy.

Qual é o correto? Se você observar, alguns padrões que o professor passou estão em uma classificação, e na internet estão em outra. Minha dúvida é saber quais dos dois está correto.

Comment: Pode sanar sua dúvida (que eu não entendi qual é): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/64969

Comment: Se você observar, alguns padrões que o professor passou estão em uma classificação, e na internet estão em outra, minha dúvida é saber quais dos dois está correto

Comment: Os dois podem estar certos. Eu creio que ambos estejam certos, inclusive. (Vou aqui comentar apenas acerca do formato da pergunta, comentar sobre a sua dúvida vai exigir outro comentário pois já estou esgotando o limite de caracteres). Eu só pude observar que você pôs o achado da internet em contraponto devido ao seu comentário, tente editar sua pergunta para deixar ele melhor estruturada. Sobre uma boa formatação de pergunta, minha dica é: use texto plano; letras, pontuação, hífen, dígitos quando está falando de números, aspas, $ para falar em quantidades...

Comment: É o seguinte, eu sou novo em design patterns e eu estava vendo o Visitor, nos slides do professor dizia que era estrutural e na internet diz que ele é comportamental, isso está embaralhando minha mente

Comment: ... Use parágrafos normalmente; para o parágrafo ter efeito, você precisa deixar uma linha em branco entre dois blocos de texto. Cada bloco de texto é considerado um parágrafo. Se você precisar citar parte pequena de código (não é o seu caso, apenas dica futura), use o tick: "\`". Se precisar itemizar ou enumerar coisas (isso já se refere ao que você deseja), use a notação do Markdown para isso: comece um novo bloco de texto, use "-" (para item) ou "1."  (para enumeração) no começo da linha, dê um espaço, coloque o item

Comment: Sobre sua dúvida, isso pode ser visto com outro ponto de vista. Esse ponto de vista foca no conhecimento propriamente dito. Se alguém lhe falar que retas paralelas sempre se tocam, essa pessoa está errada? Não necessariamente. Se ela estiver no contexto de geometria plana, ela poderia estar falando poeticamente de "encontro no infinito", mas em geometria esférica todas as retas são paralelas entre si e em todo par de retas elas se encontram em dois pontos diametralmente opostos; em geometria hiperbólica entretanto essa afirmação é totalmente falsa, nem sua versão poética estaria aceitável...

Comment: ... Então, assim como existem diversas geometrias com diversas características distintas, você tem diversas teorias sobre o mesmo assunto. Às vezes dois teóricos podem ser mutuamente excludentes, mas o tópico abordado é o mesmo. Talvez essas diferenças se deem por uma simples interpretação de diretriz, talvez porque seu professor considerou como verdade "A" mas GoF considerou "B"... mas ambas as visões mesmo que contraditórias podem estar certas

Comment: Só vi seu comentário agora, estava terminando de escrever meus "breves" comentários e editando sua pergunta... Falando em "editando sua pergunta", você tinha colocado travessões e não traços, sabe o trabalho que me deu para colocar traço em tudo? Estou usando um celular para isso, então nem vem dizer que era só por no "notepad" e rodar um _replace_... Enfim, meus comentários anteriores respondem a isso que você escreveu: teóricos distintos sobre a mesma teoria podem se contradizer e ambos podem estar certos. Tente descobrir qual foi o teórico do seu professor e quais critérios ele usou aí

Comment: Os exemplos do seu professor tinham alguns erros de digitação, tal como "Fly***W***eig***th***" ao invés de "Fly***w***eig***ht***" e também "Chai***r*** of Respons***a***bility" ao invés de "Chai***n*** of Respons***i***bility". Deixei eles da forma como estavam, mas não falei disso na resposta porque não é esse o propósito da pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os padrões em que há divergência quanto a classificação na sua pergunta são o Bridge, o Chain of responsibility, o Flyweight, o Interpreter, o Mediator, o Memento e o Visitor.

Vamos começar com os mais fáceis:

- O Chain of responsibility tem a finalidade de encapsular sequências de **comportamentos**. Esse padrão permite pendurar esses comportamentos uns nos outros e ainda assim manter eles isolados uns dos outros, tal como os elos de uma corrente. Como o foco é encapsular **comportamentos**, esse é um padrão comportamental.
- A ideia do Flyweight é reutilizar e compartilhar estados das classes para reduzir consumo de memória e de processamento. Ou seja, trata-se de uma otimização que não deveria ter impacto no comportamento dos objetos. Logo, esse é um padrão **estrutural**.
- O objetivo do Interpreter é definir como uma expressão pode ser interpretada. Ou seja, definir qual é o **comportamento** de uma expressão. Logo, esse é um padrão **comportamental**.
- O Memento é um padrão que visa prover a objetos o **comportamento** de salvar e restaurar uma cópia salva sem violar o encapsulamento. Como o foco é prover um comportamento a um objeto, esse é um padrão **comportamental**.
- O Visitor é um padrão que tem como objetivo prover um tipo de polimorfismo denominado de *double dispatch*, onde o **comportamento** a ser realizado depende não apenas da instância sobre a qual um método é chamado, mas também do tipo do parâmetro utilizado na chamada. Como o foco aqui é o comportamento polimórfico desejado, este é um padrão **comportamental**.

Agora os mais difíceis:

- O Bridge tem como finalidade prover dois ou mais níveis de flexibilidade de implementação em uma hierarquia de classes. Vou tomar como exemplo [essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/319757/540552), mas dar uma mudadinha no exemplo para torná-lo um pouco mais real:

  Imagine que você esteja modelando formas geométricas que podem ter texturas. Com isso, você pode ter uma interface para uma forma geométrica com uma implementação de círculos, uma de retângulo e uma de triângulo. Entretanto, criar uma implementação de triângulo listrado, uma de triângulo com gradiente, uma de triângulo de uma cor só, uma de retângulo listrado, uma de retângulo com gradiente, etc. seria um exagero. A solução é você definir uma interface para a textura e dizer que uma forma geométrica tem uma textura.

  O problema a ser resolvido é o de prover múltiplas hierarquias de **comportamentos** distintos a uma classe, mas o problema que esse padrão busca resolver não é o de como dar esses comportamentos à classe e sim como organizar isso tudo. Por este motivo, esse é um padrão **estrutural**.
- O Mediator tem como finalidade encapsular o **comportamento** de dois objetos que não deveriam se conhecer diretamente (o que é uma questão **estrutural**). O motivo dele ser considerado **comportamental** é porque a ideia dele é encapsular **comportamentos**.

Ou seja, a classificação que você achou na internet é a que está correta.

Comment: Ou seja, as duas referências tem seus erros?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Não. O que ele achou na internet está correto.

Comment: Estranho, então eu li uma coisa diferente do que estava de fato no texto, vou tentar ler com atenção redobrada

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Editei a pergunta para ter certeza do que estava lendo, pois os padrões foram apresentados em ordens diferentes e isso me confundiu um pouco, de forma a atrasar o desenvolvimento da minha resposta em uns minutos. Mesmo assim, ainda vou reler mais uma vez para ter certeza que não houve nenhuma confusão.

Comment: a confusão foi minha mesmo. A edição ficou ótima. Revisei ela e está em acordo com o estado anterior da publicação. E eu creio que o estado anterior (minha edição) estava coerente com a original.