# Como um método com mesmo nome retorna mais de um tipo de objeto?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, google-drive-api

Estou implementando o [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

```
var fileMetadata = new GoogleDriveAPIV3.Data.File()
        {
            Name = "folderTest/testeUpload.jpg"
        };
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request1 = new DriveConnection().ReturnDriveService().Files.Create(
                fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");


var fileMetadata2 = new GoogleDriveAPIV3.Data.File()
        {
            Name = "FolderTest",
            MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
        };
FilesResource.CreateRequest request2 = new DriveConnection().ReturnDriveService().Files.Create(fileMetadata);
```

O método `Create` está retornando dois tipos de Objeto (`CreateMediaUpload` ou `CreateRequest`) e essa diferenciação está ocorrendo quando passo um parâmetro diferente.

Como pode ocorrer **um** método retornar mais de um objeto *diferente* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe um padrão de projeto ([Design Pattern](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96452/o-que-%C3%A9-design-pattern)) chamado fábrica (*Factory*).

*Factory* é um *Design Pattern* para criação de objetos.

A *Factory* sabe qual objeto criar de acordo com os parâmetros que ela recebe.

Logo, ao implementarmos esse padrão e tentar criar o objeto, internamente a Factory se encarrega de retornar o objeto, que pode ser diferente, dependendo dos parâmetros informados.

Nesse exemplo que você informou, ao criar o objeto usando `new DriveConnection().ReturnDriveService().Files.Create(...)`, internamente a *Factory* ao receber os parâmetros pode retornar um objeto ou outro.

Exemplo (esse exemplo é apenas para entendimento básico de como um método poderia retornar mais de um tipo de objeto, mas se deseja saber mais detalhes sobre o padrão de projeto *Factory* dê uma olhada [aqui](https://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern)):

Imagine que `CreateMediaUpload` e `CreateRequest` implementam a mesma interface chamada `ICreate`. Vamos supor que existe uma classe que será a nossa `Factory` com um método assim:

```
public ICreate Create(....)
{
  // De acordo com os parâmetros, pode ser retornado um tipo CreateMediaUpload ou CreateRequest
}
```

Nesse exemplo, a *Factory* pode disponibilizar um método para criação de diferentes objetos que implementam a interface `ICreate`.

**Edição:**

Outro exemplo onde um método pode retornar mais de um objeto diferente:

Imagine que a classe `Files` abaixo disponibilize dois métodos `Create` com parâmetros diferentes, dependendo dos parâmetros um tipo de objeto é retornado:

```
public class Files 
{
    public CreateMediaUpload Create(string fileMetadata, string stream, string imageType)
    {            
        return new CreateMediaUpload(fileMetadata, stream, imageType);
    }

    public CreateRequest Create(CreateMediaUpload createMediaUpload)
    {
        return new CreateRequest(createMediaUpload);
    }
 }
```

Ao usar `Files.Create(...)` apesar do nome do método ser `Create` posso obter objetos diferentes.

Comment: Muito bom, ótima resposta, tirou minha duvida.

Comment: Não consegui verificar se as classes referidas implementam a mesma interface ou têm algum tipo de herança em comum. Mesmo que `CreateMediaUpload` e `CreateRequest` implementem a mesma interface, sendo que `Create(....)` retorna a *interface*, não é permitido fazer `CreateMediaUpload nomeVar = factory.Create(....);`, a não ser que seja feito um *cast* explicito: `CreateMediaUpload nomeVar = (CreateMediaUpload)factory.Create(....)`, o que não é feito no código da pergunta. Ou o código da pergunta não compila ou terá de haver outra explicação, algo que não me ocorre ou desconheço.

Comment: @ramaral Eu não sou conhecedor dos objetos do Google Drive API e não tenho o código original da pergunta para saber mais detalhes, a resposta está mais voltada a pergunta conceitual **Como pode ocorrer um método retornar mais de um objeto diferente ?** pois ele não levantou nenhum problema de erro de compilação na pergunta. Sequer me preocupei com outras questões a não ser essa pergunta. Se puder ajudar poste uma resposta aí para gente compartilhando seu conhecimento também :-)

Comment: Eu concordo com a sua resposta, nos termos do seu comentário. Não tenho nada a acrescentar a não ser a necessidade de haver o *cast* explicito, que não aparece no código da pergunta. Note também que o cast pode "passar" em tempo de compilação mas falhar em tempo de execução.

Comment: Não há necessidade do uso de cast ao implementar o padrão de projeto Factory, em caso de dúvidas eu disponibilizei um link de referência a um implementação completa de Factory na resposta :-)

Comment: Confirma ou não que o seguinte é verdadeiro: Se o método retorna uma interface terá de fazer *cast* para o objecto concreto se o quiser usar como tal. `CreateMediaUpload nomeVar = factory.Create(....);` não compila, ou usa *cast* ou usa `ICreate nomeVar = factory.Create(....);`

Comment: Adicionei outro exemplo, com um cenário um pouco diferente, para tentar melhorar a resposta e deixar mais claro.

Comment: Agora sim, o exemplo dado explica o exemplo da pergunta. Agora já posso dar o meu +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

De uma olhada na assinatura desses objetos:

[FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1FilesResource_1_1CreateMediaUpload.html)

[FilesResource.CreateRequest](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1FilesResource_1_1CreateRequest.html)

Tanto `CreateMediaUpload` e `CreateRequest` são funções que retorna objetos(Object Factory) então seu método `Create` retorna uma referência para uma função. Função essa, que por sua vez retorna um objeto especifico.

Comment: Augusto como assim são funções? n são objetos ja que estão declarados antes do nome do mesmo ?