# Qual é a diferença entre Strategy Pattern e Specification Pattern

Tags: c#, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, strategy-pattern

Estou implementando um *app* CLI em C# de jogo da velha e queria saber qual é a melhor *pattern* para utilizar para fazer a "AI" que seria o *player vs computer* no caso.

Andei olhando algumas *patterns* para fazer isso e me surgiu a dúvida de qual utilizar.

Minha dúvida pela implementação da Strategy e da Specification é que as duas são para validar algum tipo de entrada e retornar o resultado provável para aquele valor de entrada. Qual seria a diferença de implementação entre as duas e qual é a sua usabilidade, quando devo utilizar a Strategy e quando devo optar pela Specification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, um jogo da velha precisa de um desses padrões? Então tá.

A principal diferença é que o padrão da estratégia é isolado, indica uma regra a ser aplicada de acordo com uma implementação externa em algum ponto específico, e pode parametrizar qualquer comportamento desejado no objeto. E o padrão da especificação é algo mais complexo e estabelece um conjunto de regras, geralmente encadeadas, que serão aplicadas em alguma parte, sendo que cada regra individual pode ser trocada, adicionada ou removida, além de mudar a ordem, e estas regras devem ser principalmente validações (em um sentido amplo, e não só a validação tradicional, pode ser uma seleção por exemplo), portanto bem mais limitada. Portando nem deveria haver confusão, eles servem a propósitos bem diferentes. Geralmente a dúvida sobre o uso do Strategy é se não seria melhor o Bridge, Adapter, State, Template Method, Decorator, e por vezes Visitor ou Facade.

Já tenho minhas dúvidas se deveria usar um deles, mas o Specification parece menos interessante aí, ainda que eu possa estar errado por não conhecer os detalhes. Quanto mais vai aplicando essas coisas tende a adotar o *antipattern* chamado [Second System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-system_effect). Por outro lado se quiser insistir nele, talvez queira usar como mecanismo de "AI", e pode fazer sentido já que quer complicar a solução, usar este padrão para encadear as decisões. Lembre que ele é só um `if` bem mais complicado, é OOP sendo usada onde o simples imperativo resolvia o problema. E se varia o que fazer em certas sequências então o Strategy pode ser útil, mas acho que nem é o caso, pense até em outros que eu citei acima. Eu não posso pensar por não ter detalhes.

Note que C# tem mecanismos que muitas vezes faz com que um certo padrão não seja necessário. Por isso sempre digo: as pessoas querem usar [*design patterns*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101) sem nem mesmo saber o que isto significa, é só porque está na moda.

> Design patterns are bug reports against your programming language
>
> -- Peter Norvig

- [Detalhamento](http://norvig.com/design-patterns/design-patterns.pdf).
- [Paul Graham também fala algo sobre isto](http://www.paulgraham.com/icad.html).
- [Discussão](http://wiki.c2.com/?AreDesignPatternsMissingLanguageFeatures).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!