# Por que certos domínios são mais fáceis de modelar que outros?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, gui, jogos, projeto-de-software

Já ouvi falar, a respeito de certos domínios, como GUIs e jogos, que são mais "abstraídos", ou já se tratam de abstrações, ou são "mecanismos", enfim, possuem uma distinção em relação a outros domínios. Não que eles sejam semelhantes a ponto de serem colocados no mesmo balaio, mas ouço falar que são diferentes em relação a outros tipos de domínios.

Com isso, eles seriam mais fáceis de serem modelados em orientação a objetos.

Como se dá essa distinção? Que vantagens se encontra na hora de modelar esses domínios? Quais outros domínios entram nesse cenário? Como identificar um domínio com essas características? GUIs e jogos realmente têm algo em comum nesse aspecto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu acho que a resposta está na pergunta. Porque eles já são abstrações. E o programador pode fazer como ele acha melhor. Pelo menos quem criou o modelo inicial pode.

## Mecanismos ou modelos abstratos

É lindo você fazer um jogo onde você tem total controle sobre o que acontecerá, portanto controla o domínio. Você pode até decidir não colocar algo no modelo se ele te prejudicar em alguma coisa no código.

E mais, jogos tendem a ter pouca ou nenhuma manutenção em produção. Depois que lança tá pronto e não se fala mais nisso. Mesmo uma versão nova tende a ser outro código, mesmo que aproveite algo do anterior, não tem compatibilidade. Modelos errados não causam problemas futuros. Mas essa não é a maior vantagem.

Em jogo é tudo muito simples, o soldado não é um soldado de fato, é um objeto que se sabe ser uma ideia quase arbitrária do que é um soldado, ele não precisa fazer cosias de soldado, ele precisa fazer uma ou outra ação que o jogo definiu que o solado faz. Ainda assim pode ter complicações, veja os comentários abaixo.

Em GUI você estabelece quais objetos abstratos terá, como seles devem se comportar e como evolui (muito pouco).

Rust não é OO. Tenta fazer GUI com ela, é uma dor de cabeça. Alguns dizem ser melhor, mas GUIs não prosperam com ela, o reúso é muito complicado.

Quando você lida com um domínio baseado em funções do sistema operacional ou banco de dados, que são mecanismos, como essas coisas mudam? Quase não mudam porque é tudo pensando para não mudar, os consumidores são outros códigos que precisam de estabilidade. E quando falha e descobre que estava bem errado, é simples resolver, faz outro e mantém o anterior como legado.

Um sistema de criptografia não tem muito o que inventar. Um controle interno do sistema, geralmente não mexe, autenticação muita muito pouco, mesmo que precise evita-se fazer mudanças fundamentais e mesmo assim o uso costuma ser opcional.

Todos mecanismos acima, tudo feito para ficar mais ou menos congelado.

Note a diferença para o mecanismo do banco de dados e o modelo do domínio que montara uma base de dados específica.

## Domínios de mundo real

Agora vai pro mundo real, em geral questões de negócios que mudam quase todos os dias, por força de legislação, atualização tecnologia que não é de computadores, é da indústria que está trabalhando, de práticas gerais, de mercado, o que acha que acontece com seu modelo?

#### Falácia do especialista de domínio

Mais ainda, quem define como é esse modelo? Nos exemplos dos mecanismos você vê que foram engenheiros experientes que fizeram o modelo, passou pelo crivo de muita gente ou pelo menos os objetos eram simples demais. Tudo muito estável.

Em negócios geralmente você não tem uma pessoa que entende tudo como aquele domínio de fato é. E mesmo quando ela entende nem sempre consegue prever o futuro.

Por isso eu dou risada quando os promotores de DDD falam em "especialistas do domínio". Isto costuma ser uma figura que não existe de fato. É um monte de gente tentando acertar alguma coisa, e em geral não sabem o que estão fazendo. Elas lidam com aquilo todo dia e não conseguem fazer uma definição do que é de fato cada coisa, qual o limite de cada coisa, o tal do *bounded context*. As pessoas tentam adivinhar. Por vezes dá certo, mas nem sempre. Claro que existem pessoas que fazem isso um pouco melhor, mas modelo um pouco melhor e um ruim tem uma diferença muito pequena, e uma distância bem grande para o modelo perfeito que é necessário (perfeito não é a mesma coisa que definitivo).

## Complexidade do mundo real

Você já viu alguém ensinando OOP com um exemplo do mundo real? Com toda complexidade onde o tal do `Animal` lida com tudo o que um animal deve lidar em um sistema? Se mostrarem as milhares de classes necessárias para fazer isso direito todo mundo desiste.

Você começa ser obrigado colocar mecanismos que permitem o objeto evoluir melhor, vai ficando complexo.

Mecanismo aqui é algo que não importa para o domínio, só para o software conseguir organizar o domínio.

Mesmo que você faça boa abstração, encapsulamento adequado, e vamos até tirar a questão da herança que é outra coisa que complica muito porque acopla, ainda assim precisa ter pequenos objetos demais para compor o objeto principal. Até aí dá trabalho mas pode não ser um grande problema porque você fez certo o que está no começo do parágrafo. Mas pelo menos parte dessas capacidade internas do objeto acabam se tornando contratos do objeto e algo público, todo consumidor dele precisa saber daquilo. Inclusive em alguns casos, nem que seja por um parâmetro que passa precisa saber alguns detalhes que não parecem ser tão públicos, o que é [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101).

## Mudança é a única constante

Mais cedo ou mais tarde você descobrirá que algo foi mal definido e agora criará um monumento de trabalho para acertar para funcionar de acordo com uma mudança que aconteceu no mundo real.

Quando você modela algo fixo e abstrato o objeto é aquilo, é fácil ver o que ele é. Quando modela regras de negócios fica obscuro, difícil de enxergar e uma mudança pode invalidar aquele modelo se não foi muito bem pensado. O que vale hoje pode não valer depois. Os comentários abaixo mostram que mesmo em casos assim pode ser complicado fazer certo.

Quando modela uma regra de negócio você tenta acertar quais as questões ligadas a aquele objeto do mundo real (que nem sempre é um objeto mesmo) devem fazer parte do mundo do computador. E justamente alguns objetos nem existem no mundo real, mas são necessários no mundo computacional. Talvez o segredo de toda resposta esteja aqui. **Abstrair o concreto é muito difícil quando o objeto deve saber tudo o que ele é capaz**.

No mundo real o objeto sempre tem todas capacidades que ele precisa e humanos não conseguem perceber isso direito em quase todas situações. É complexo demais para um humano.

## Isolar comportamentos torna mais fácil compor

Se você abstrai números inteiros, você sabe tudo o que ele pode fazer? Na prática sabe quase nada, a maioria, se não for tudo, do que poderá acontecer com ele será definido longe dele, não orientado a objeto, e ele não pode ser estendido, fica muito mais fácil.

Aí se você se prepara demais para essas mudanças o sistema fica complexo demais sem trazer nenhum benefício concreto para o negócio (foi assim só para facilitar uma potencial manutenção). Se o sistema for muito simples precisa de muito esforço para manutenção. Você nunca acerta o ponto porque não consegue prever o futuro e que partes do objeto que você não modelou serão necessários depois.

Em sistemas onde os comportamentos são mais isolados tende ser mais fácil fazer essas mudanças. O objeto é muito mais simples do que feito pensando OO e tem menos espaço pro erro e mais flexibilidade por ter coisas mais intercambiáveis.

Em geral mecanismos não possuem muita herança ou possuem composições simples e óbvias. As heranças são simples e fixas e em geral é por causa do reúso.

Qual é a solução para manter a sanidade de modelos de regras de negócios? Adotar um monte de *design pattern* mesmo que não precise, mas vai que possa precisar depois. Se não adotar de cara, o contrato daquele objeto pode precisar mudar, e contrato mudando pode tornar tudo viral.

E falo de contrato em código ou contrato tácito. Nos comentários abaixo falo disso. OO funciona melhor em linguagem com plena liberdade de como modelar o objeto, a tal ponto que que deixa tudo lento (que não importa para alguns, a linguagem que as pessoas mais usam que se aproxima disso é Ruby, trágica de lenta) e menos robusto e o código tem que ficar controlando todo tipo de problema que pode aparecer, e haja teste, haja cobertura para se aproximar de algo confiável. Aí muitas vezes fica tão complicado que o pessoal prefere um *framework* que piora os indicadores ruins, mas que facilita alcançar um resultado melhor.

## Falácia do desacoplamento

Se você seguir o que as pessoas falam para fazer vira uma loucura. Imagine um objeto que seja um produto. Isso pode mudar a todo momento. Pode adotar a técnica que for, um campo novo nele obrigará o sistema inteiro ser modificado, a não ser que faça um mecanismo que tente ficar "advinhando" todos comportamentos possíveis e executando, provavelmente com reflexão. Pode funcionar em alguns casos, mas fica algo bem complexo e nada eficiente. E em algum momento não funcionará bem. Tudo terá que ser feito pensando nesse mecanismo e talvez o objeto não seja o ideal para fazer isso.

Talvez o comportamento deveria ser o centro da questão aqui, você muda o campo e não precisa se preocupar com o banco de dados, com o modelo básico, com a tela x ou y, com um certo processamento, etc.

Muitas vezes para tentar não vazar a abstração, que na prática é impossível em todos casos, é necessário aumentar muito a complexidade do todo enfiando mecanismos auxiliares. E alguns dirão que só o fato de ter que lidar com mecanismos que não são do domínio já é um vazamento.

## Conclusão

Quantas vezes eu vi as pessoas tentarem modelar bem o domínio e criar um [*second-system*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/380604/101) (vide comentários abaixo). Tem objeto que tem mais complexidade para seu próprio gerenciamento de complexidade do que o que ele deveria fazer.

E quantas vezes vi desenvolvedor falando para o usuário que não dá para fazer o que ele quer. Mas no mundo real dá. Não dá no modelo que ele criou.

Talvez o resumo seja:

> Andar na água e desenvolver software a partir de uma especificação são fáceis se ambos estiverem congelados.
>
> — Edward Berard

Mecanismos possuem especificações congeladas, negócios não.

Eu não acho que importa muito o domínio, o importante é saber o que fazer, independente do que ele é. Regras não ajudarão muito, mas regras são mais facilmente aplicadas a mecanismos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Adorei a citação

Comment: Teria um exemplo de mecanismo?

Comment: E qual é a relação disso tudo com aqueles [artigos](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/amp/) do Eric Lippert sobre design de um Wizards and Warriors?

Comment: Mecanismo é tudo o que só diz respeito à aplicação, que não faz parte da solução para o usuário. É a GUI (não ela aplicada, mas o que já existe antes da sua aplicação é o mecanismo para construir a sua interface com o usuário), é tudo que o que conversa com SO ou serviços como banco de dados, é uma configuração do software, ou o sistema de autenticação, um controle de workflow ou de update automático, tudo coisas subjacentes ao problema. O MVC em si é um mecanismo, algum *design pattern* também. Eventualmente algo ligado ao domínio mas não o que está na linha de frente, o meio e não o fim.

Comment: O Eric mostrou como as coisas são difíceis e como as soluções são falhas. E que para ter a capacidade de reproduzir o mundo real (e esse nem é um mundo real mesmo, é um inventado) precisa de muita complexidade, precisa de mecanismos que auxiliem o domínio. Demonstra que linguagens verdadeiramente orientadas a objeto possuem mais capacidade de lidar com isso e que o que as pessoas usam é algo mais ou menos OO, como eu sempre disse, o que faz bem menos sentido usar assim, mas as pessoas insistem. E uma linguagem OO de verdade é bem pouco robusta. Você tem que escolher o veneno.

Comment: Linguagens OO de verdade, como é Smalltalk são lentas e se o código não for muito bem escrito terá muitas falhas porque ele é flexível o suficiente para lidar com tudo o que pode acontecer com o objeto, mas também não tem como o compilador te ajudar muito. Nas linguagens que as pessoas usam pra conseguir o mesmo efeito tem que por um monte de penduricalho e vai ficando complexo. Por isso esquecer a ideia de objeto como um emulador do mundo real poderia ajudar.