# É correto numa classe DTO ter atributos de duas ou mais tabelas?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Preciso retornar num REST dados de duas tabelas, para ser consumidos em uma App Android/IOS, desenvolvida com xamarin. Como eu retorno um DTO, achei por bem trazer nesse DTO dados de duas tabelas, mas acho isso um tanto gambi. A outra solução, seria retornar dois DTO, aí seriam dois serviços, um preenchendo a Listview de Liberação e o outro preenchendo a Listview de Itens. Não sei qual seria a melhor abordagem. Abaixo meu DTO.

```
public class LiberacaoItensDTO
    {
        //Mapeamento dos campos, pois estava dando erro de cast e assim resolveu
        public LiberacaoItensDTO()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, Liberacao>()
                .ForMember(d => d.DataLib, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => DataLib.ToString()));
            });
        }

        //Dados da tabela Liberação
        public int IdLiberacao { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int IdVendedor { get; set; }
        public string Vendedor { get; set; }
        public int IdFilial { get; set; }
        public string Filial { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float? DataLib { get; set; }
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Juros { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Desconto { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public double Vencimento { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public double Acrescimo { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Entrada { get; set; }

        //Dados da tabela de ItensLib
        public int IdProduto { get; set; }
        public string Produto { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Qtde { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Unitario { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float CustoDiario { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public double UltCondicao { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Total { get; set; }
    }
```

Método para trazer o DTO no serviço

```
public List<LiberacaoDTO> getAutoriza(int idorcamento)
        {

            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes??????? Faria um Join com as duas tabelas, liberacao e itenslib
                        .Where(lib => lib.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)
                        .Select(lib => new LiberacaoItensDTO
                        {
                            //Aqui coloco os campos retornados
                        }).ToList();
            return lista;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe limite de uma DTO representar apenas uma entidade, o objetivo da DTO é transferir um objeto. Se a sua consulta trouxe dois registros, nada mais justo que sua DTO represente os dois. Imagine sintaticamente a linguagem SQL, quando eu faço um JOIN no sql eu não coloco dentro do meu SELECT ambas propriedades do JOIN?

Sobre dois serviços, são duas consultas (e dois processo de conectar com o banco, serializar, etc.) que você vai estar fazendo sendo que você pode trazer todas em uma só. Em regra geral salvo algumas exceções, fazer JOIN é sempre mais performático que fazer várias consultas.

Recomendo: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42998/are-individual-queries-faster-than-joins

Comment: O problema está nos campos float ou double. Me dá esse erro: `The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Double' type to the 'System.Single' type is not valid.`

Comment: Problema? Você não citou nenhum problema de cast na pergunta.

Comment: Eu sei, para a questão postada está resolvido. O problema é quando eu coloco campos float, um problema que eu vinha passando, sumiu, achei que havia resolvido e agora começou novamente, por isso o comentário. Quanto a resposta para essa pergunta, ok, está resolvido.

Answer (score 3):

[DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) é um objeto criado para transportar dados e reduzir o número de chamadas remotas.

Então, não há problemas em trazer dados de duas tabelas no seu DTO (não é gambiarra :-)). Muito pelo contrário, fazendo dessa forma será realizada uma só consulta/chamada remota ao invés de duas.

Já quanto a segunda solução sugerida, dependendo da sua implementação pode vir a exigir duas chamadas remotas, você estaria sujeito a problemas de latência inerentes à uma comunicação/consultas remotas, o que aumenta o tempo de resposta, já que seriam dois serviços.

Em suma, o uso de um único DTO no seu cenário é mais interessante para reduzir o número de chamadas remotas, enquanto a segunda opção vai totalmente no sentido contrário.

Answer (score 1):

DTO ou Data Transfer Object ou Transfer Object é um modelo que você define para o transporte de dados entre diferentes componentes de um sistema, diferentes instâncias ou processos de um sistema distribuído ou diferentes sistemas via serialização ou até mesmo via rede / webservices.

A ideia é você agrupar um conjunto de informações para que você não tenha que fazer várias chamadas para popular uma VIEW ou GRID, ou seja, você não está fazendo gambiarra, isso é uma forma normal de manipular ou trafegar dados.

Além de agrupar os dados como dito acima, existem outros detalhes onde, utilizar DTO's nos ajuda a resolver determinados problemas, segue:

- Remover Referências Circulares. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference)
- Ocultar algumas propriedades que você não deseja disponibilizar de forma explícita.
- Desacoplar a camada de serviço do banco de dados.

Segue uma pergunta a respeito de DTO no SOpt:
[O que é um DTO?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31362/o-que-%C3%A9-um-dto)

Segue um tutorial da Microsoft onde é sugerido a utilização de DTO:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5